# is this a bad way of handling in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to monkey patch or extend enumerable.  I want to handle nil cases as well and I have come up with the following test case and extensions:

```
module Enumerable
  def has_elements
    (self) && (self.size > 0)
  end
end

class NilClass
  def has_elements
    false
  end
end

class EnumerableExtensionsTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  should "return false for nil" do
    d = nil

    assert_equal(false, d.has_elements)
  end

end
```

The test passes but this feels wrong and I was wondering if there is a better way of returning false for a call to has_elements, or how should I handle this?

Comment: First of all if you're inside `Enumerable#has_elements`, `self` can't be `nil`, so there's no need to check for that. You can just define `has_elements` as `not empty?`. Secondly not all enumerables have a `size` method. Third it's convention in ruby that methods which return a boolean end with `?`. Fourth the best way to handle this would be to not touch `NilClass` and simply make sure that all your methods which return an enumerable never return nil.

Comment: Do you know about `Object#blank?` in ActiveSupport (part of Rails)?

Answer (score 0):

The [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) gem has this functionality already. If you're in Rails project, the method .empty? is available. Otherwise you'll need to include the activesupport gem and do the following inside of files that need this method:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'
```